# What to use plugins and templates in gstreamer?

Tags: gstreamer

I want to take video and audio data from gstreamer, make it ts, and start streaming.

What I'm curious about is that if you want to create an element that receives video and audio data and processes it, other than the existing elements, do you have to use a template or a plugin?
ex)
sink = gst_element_factory_make("filesink", NULL); It is a new process by making "filesink" in "myfilesink".

It seems that the concept has not been clearly captured yet.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend start reading the GStreamer plugins developer guide here:

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/plugin-development/index.html?gi-language=c

Comment: I have read the contents of this URL before. But I don't seem to understand well. I'll read it again. Thank you!